# React-Burger-Menu works on localhost, but doesn't work when pushed to Surge.sh

Tags: reactjs, webpack, configuration, hamburger-menu, surge.sh

I'm using [React-Burger-Menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-burger-menu) on a project. I've installed it with npm, imported it into my React app, and am properly displaying the hamburger menu on small screens and hiding it on large screens with the use of CSS. On small mobile screens I have `display` set to `flex` and on large screens where I want the hamburger menu hidden I have `display` set to `none`.

This works fine when I run the React app with `npm` on localhost, but when I build it with `npm run build` and push it to `Surge.sh` the hamburger menu doesn't work properly. When running the project locally on a large screen the hamburger menu is hidden and my navbar works fine. On small screens my navbar is hidden and the hamburger menu works. After pushing the project to `Surge.sh` my full screen navbar breaks and it tries to use the hamburger menu on full screen. [Here is my project with the broken hamburger/navbar](https://brochure-site.surge.sh/).

Why is my hamburger menu breaking only when I go live with the code but not when I run the project locally? Is this a problem with installation/configuration?

The docs say the following :

> The easiest way to use react-burger-menu is to install it from npm and
>   include it in your own React build process (using Browserify, Webpack,
>   etc).

I've installed React-Burger-Menu with `npm install`. Is more configuration needed with webpack in order to get it working properly when it's pushed to `Surge.sh`? What do they mean when they say include it in your own React build process using Webpack?

Comment: Please check if the `React-Burger-Menu` package is part of `dependencies` and not `devDependencies` in package.json file

Comment: It's listed as a regular dependency not a devDependency

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of your project deployed? I just checked and it seems to me like `react-burger-menu` is not used anywhere. I would suspect I will find it in `HamburgerMenu`, but it's not there.